# merge/duplicate two data sets by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two datasets by using pandas. One is location (longitude and latitude) and the other is time frame (0 to 24hrs, 15 mins step = 96 datapoints)

Here is the sample code:

```
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
s2 = pd.Series([4, 5, 6])
df = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2)],  columns =  ["A", "B", "C"])

timeframe_array=[]
for i in range(0, 3600, timeframe):
    timeframe_array.append(i)
```

And I want to get the data like this:

```
   A  B  C  time
0  1  2  3     0
1  1  2  3    15
2  1  2  3    30
3  1  2  3    45
...
```

How can I get the data like this?

Comment: By 'merge' do you mean left-join? If so: `df1.join(df2, how='left')`.

Comment: Thanks, but the time variable (0, 15, 30...) should be repeated. And sorry, I edited the original question (because it's quite hard to understand).

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure what you're looking for. Do you want time 0-3600 (step=15) replicated for each row in `df`? That is, a final dataframe with `240
* 2` = `480` total rows?

Comment: yes, you are correct. The total number of data point should be 480

Answer (score 0):

While not particularly elegant, this should work:

```
from __future__ import division  # only needed if you're using Python 2
import pandas as pd
from math import ceil

# Constants
timeframe = 15
total_t = 3600
```

Create `df1`:

```
s1 = [1, 2, 3]
s2 = [4, 5, 6]
df1 = pd.DataFrame([s1, s2], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Next, we want to build `df2` such that the sequence `0-3600` (step=15) is replicated for each row in `df1`. We can extract the number of rows with `df1.shape[0]` (which is `2` in this case).

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'time': range(0, total_t * df1.shape[0], timeframe)})
```

Next, you need to replicate the rows in `df1` to match `df2`.

```
factor = ceil(df2.shape[0] / df1.shape[0])
df1_f = pd.concat([df1] * factor).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Lastly, join the two data frames together and trim off any excess rows.

```
df3 = df1_f.join(df2, how='left')[:df2.shape[0]]
```

`Pandas` may have a built-in way to do this, but to my knowledge both `join` and `merge` can only make up a difference in rows by filling with a constant (`NaN` by default).

---

Result:

```
>>> print(df3.head(4))

   A  B  C  time
0  1  2  3     0
1  1  2  3    15
2  1  2  3    30
3  1  2  3    45

>>> print(df3.tail(4))

     A  B  C  time
476  4  5  6  7140
477  4  5  6  7155
478  4  5  6  7170
479  4  5  6  7185

>>> df3.shape  # (480, 4)
```